# My sql installer only downloading connectors

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

when I am trying to download mysql in my windows it is only showing connectors being downloaded.

whatever setup type I choose it only downloads connectors. what should i do?
[here is srnshot of instsaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay7Mc.png)
I selected developer setup type which is default setup type.

more specifically I am not getting option for downloading workbench and shell.

Comment: You have it in offline mode for whatever the reason (https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-installer-en.pdf). Do you have connectivity issues?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález oh no no i just tried it in offline mode but in online mode also i am having the same problem.

Comment: What information does the "Show Details >" button show?